# Inserting elements to create arrays in arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
myCountry = [‘Austria’, ‘Belgium’, ‘France’]
myProduct = [‘Spade’, ‘Fork’]
```

What I want is a set of ‘arrays in arrays’:

```
myMixed1 =  = [[‘Austria’, ‘Spade’], [‘Belgium’, ‘Spade’], [‘France’, ‘Spade’]]
myMixed2 =  = [[‘Austria’, ‘Fork’], [‘Belgium’, ‘Fork’], [‘France’, ‘Fork’]]
```

Been at this since yesterday trying to use the many posts on this but its now doing my head in – any ideas?

Comment: you want to do in jQuery or php?Also why you used fancy quotes, use single or double quotes

Comment: JQuery.  Perhaps the quotes is part of the reason I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sure, those quotes are invalid for use as string delimiters in JavaScript.

Comment: `Been at this since yesterday trying to use the many posts`=.please put your effort what you tried

Comment: I almost always add a fiddle/other when I ask anything on SO, but in this case my tests are tied up inside big code with other variables.  I wouldn't know which version of my tests to even start with!  As it is now I've got a lot of unpicking to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map` for this (after having fixed the quotes):

```js
const myCountry = ['Austria', 'Belgium', 'France'],
      myProduct = ['Spade', 'Fork'];

const [mixed1, mixed2] = myProduct.map( tool =>
    myCountry.map( country => [country, tool] )
);

console.log('mixed1', mixed1);
console.log('mixed2', mixed2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you're a godsend!  Works perfectly.